# use a static library compiled for different machine

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compilation, compiler-errors

I have obtained the code of a paper from the author.
The problem is that he has compiled some parts into static libraries (.a)
At the beggining I could not use it because I was having this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../lib/libmvvt.a when searching for -lmvvt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmvvt
```

I realised that it was a problem of compatibility.
I compiled the code for the rest of the libraries and now I got it working except for one library for which he did not provide the source code (only the header).

After checking inside the library with readelf, I can see that the machine is MIPS R3000.

My machine is x86-64.

Is there a way that I can use the library in my machine without having to recompile it (since I don't have the code)?

Thanks!

Comment: While the answer is an obvious 'no', I do not understand why the question itself is downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static libraries are compiled objects. The same way you can't use an executable build for one architecture in a different incompatible architecture, you can't use static library in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks @SergeyA, I don't understand either why my question was downvoted.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there a way that I can use the library in my machine without having to recompile it (since I don't have the code)

No.